# Converting hex background color into a GIF in PHP

Tags: php, image, gd, background-color

Is there any way to convert a hex color (#fffff) into a small .GIF image on the fly with PHP?

Comment: @Pekka: Sharing is caring there, Pekka..

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838794/php-image-creation-from-hex-values-in-database

Comment: `#fffff` is a hex color?

Comment: @salathe: oops... forgot another f... #ffffff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

....

```
<?php
// create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

// fill the image with the color you want
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 99, 99, 0xFFFFFF);

// set the headers and output the image
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's an answer to an incredibly lazy question, but it's still a valid answer

Comment: :( Somebody just doesn't like me.

Comment: Well, it's easy to reset the effect ;)

Comment: upvote for answering the question properly, sorry you are being harassed by haters =/

Comment: @Saad: Thanks, that worked out just as i needed it too! :o) Francis: Yeah, but you get them every time.